# Using a custom server URL with Parse on Xamarin

Tags: parsing, xamarin, back4app

I'm working on a company project that has been built over the last 18 months and has a backend built using Parse.com, we are in the progress of migrating to Back4App.

However I am unable to find how to set the API Server URL in the C# SDK which I'm using with Xamarin, as the initialise method only has parameters for an application key and a .NET key.

Would anyone know how I can set the API Server URL to http://parseapi.back4app.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply a custom `ParseClient.Configuration` that contains your Server URL:

```
ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration()
{
    Server = "http://parseapi.back4app.com",
    ApplicationId = "YourAppIDHere",
});
```

Comment: Doing this I receive the following error: `Error: The type name 'Configuration' does nopt exist in the type 'Parse Client' `

Comment: @MatthewAllen I'm using Parse package 1.7.0. You can look at the original docs: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/desktop/windows/dot_net/existing

Comment: Just realised that, my Android Parse was 1.7.0 but my IOS was only 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using an outdated version of Parse within Xamarin and I fixed this by updating my references.

To use a custom server you need Parse v1.7.0.